# In Canada, can I deduct my mortgage if running a business from my home?

Tags: canada, small-business, tax-deduction

If I run a home business and a portion of the home is used as an office for the business can I deduct a percentage of the mortgage?

Comment: Seems like you cannot:http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns206-236/229/cmmssn/hm-eng.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can claim a deduction only if *all* of your business is conducted from the home, i.e. your home is your principal place of business - not just if you work from home sometimes.

The [CRA](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/menu-e.html) (Canada Revenue Agency) has pretty strict guidelines listed [here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tp/it514/README.html), but once you're sure you qualify for a deduction, the next step would be to determine what portion of your home qualifies.

*You cannot attempt to deduct your entire mortgage simply because you run your business out of your home.*

The portion of your mortgage and other related & allowable home expense deductions has to be pro-rated to be equal to or less than the portion of your home you use for business.  Simply put, if your business is operated out of a 120 sq-ft self-contained space, and your home's total square-footage is 2400 sq-ft, you can deduct 5% of your expenses (120/2,400 = 0.05).

Hope this helps!

Comment: (Sorry, I think my earlier edit suggestion was incorrect - I've rolled it back to what you had.)

Comment: One point that needs to be addressed: you can deduct a certain percentage of mortgage *interest*, not mortgage *principal*.